# Error when defining my own module as a virtual field in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Why can't I do this:

```
  defmodule M1 do
    defstruct [:a, :b, :c, :d]
    # other stuff
  end


  # ...............

  schema "my_model" do
    # .................
    field :my_field, M1, virtual: true
```

Error

```
      ** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type MyApp.M1 for field :my_field
```

The module M1 is resolved but why is it disallowed to use it?

Comment: Does `M1` have `@behaviour Ecto.Type`?

Comment: @Dogbert, no....

Comment: That’s the answer to your question: the module should implement `Ecto.Type` behaviour to be used as `Ecto` type, what is clearly specified in the documentation.

Comment: @mudasobwa, that's not **clearly** specified

Comment: “Defines functions and the `Ecto.Type` behaviour for **implementing custom types**.” — https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html#content

Comment: @mudasobwa, that's not a custom type, it's a virtual type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store an `M1` struct in the field, you can disable Ecto's type checking by specifying the type to be `:any`, which will let you store anything at all in the field:

```
field :my_field, :any, virtual: true
```

There's no way that I see to make Ecto check that the field is a struct of module `M1` unless you implement `Ecto.Type` behaviour for that module.